# Can we get better precision on rate fields in the info object?

Tags: feature-request

Most of the fields returned in the [info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/info) object are totals, so they're perfect.  Some of them are rates though.

- answers_per_minute
- badges_per_minute
- questions_per_minute

Having these fields set at a *per minute* resolution makes sense for Stack Overflow, but for many (most?) of the sites in the network, these values have no precision.  I noticed this when looking at the results for [The Workplace](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=workplace&run=true):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "total_questions": 2319,
      "total_unanswered": 3,
      "total_accepted": 1420,
      "total_answers": 8541,
      "questions_per_minute": 0,
      "answers_per_minute": 0.01,
      "total_comments": 28925,
      "total_votes": 91670,
      "total_badges": 17680,
      "badges_per_minute": 0.02,
      "total_users": 8526,
      "new_active_users": 4,
      "api_revision": "2013.10.9.8200"
    }
  ],
  "quota_remaining": 9981,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": false
}
```

Note that `questions_per_minute` is 0, making it impossible to scale up.  `answers_per_minute` isn't much better at 0.01.  Would it make sense to add precision to the values returned in these fields?  Is more precision available?